# Change select value in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need your help !

I'm on a project for my compagny and I should create a select field that can be duplicate with React. So, I have a little problem when I want to save my selection, if I refresh the page, the default option still the same (and not the selected one). There is my code for select.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Select extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(data) {
    this.setState({value:data.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <label>
          <select className="widefat" name={this.props.name} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;
```

I change the default value :

[When i change the select option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyRLL.png)

[After a refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gshbS.png)

I think it's because in select.js It initialize the value to '' and don't save the selection but I don't know how to save the selection.

Comment: Use localStorage for it or if you people are using redux-storage you can save the value in redux store . redux-storage will save the value for you in session storage

Comment: How did you implement this in my code ? Sorry but  I never use React redux ans I discover react 3 days ago. thx

Comment: Ok so , use localStorage API to set value. In constructor, you can define the initial State. Read through the localStorage documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way to accomplish this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Select extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.value }; // can be initialized by <Select value='someValue' />
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <label>
          <select className="widefat" value={this.state.value} name={this.props.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;
```

**Going further**

You could iterate in a map in the render method to implement this like so:

```
  render() {
    const dictionary = [
      { value: 'grapefruit', label: 'Grapefruit' },
      { value: 'lime', label: 'Lime' },
      { value: 'coconut', label: 'Coconut' },
      { value: 'mango', label: 'Mango' }
    ];

    return (
        <label>
          <select
            className="widefat"
            value={this.state.value}
            name={this.props.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            {dictionary.map(
              // Iterating over every entry of the dictionary and converting each
              // one of them into an `option` JSX element
              ({ value, label }) => <option key={value} value={value}>{label}</option>
            )}
          </select>
        </label>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your both answers doesn't work for me. I have this warning :

Comment: Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.

Comment: I updated my answer. In fact, it's simpler this way (thanks to the react warning, I learned something new today)

Answer (score 0):

The target event property returns the element that triggered the event. It stores a lot of properties, print it to the console, that would familiarize with its capabilities

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Select extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
  }

  handleChange = e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
     <label>
       <select className="widefat" name={this.props.name} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
        <option value="lime">Lime</option>
        <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
        <option value="mango">Mango</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;
```

Comment: Code only answers to dont explain a solution. Please go ahead and explain yourself, why and how you solve the problem and what OP might have done wrong or missed out.

Comment: Then this is probably your place to go: [Stack Overflow based on the russian lanuage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Since the normal Stack Overflow is English only, please avoid any russian language and try to speak english or switch to the linked website.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'll decide where I stand :)

Answer (score -1):

After a long journey to search in documentation and in the depth of internet I found my answer. I forgot to add a "for" for my label. There is my final code :

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Select extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: this.props.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <label htmlFor={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}
          <select defaultValue={this.props.value}  id={this.props.id} className="widefat" name={this.props.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
            <option>Aucun</option>
            <option value="55">Option 2</option>
            <option value="126">Backend configuration & installation</option>
            <option value="125">Frontend integration</option>
            <option value="124">Graphic Design</option>
          </select>
        </label>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;
```